# unable to make cross domain calls using jquery ajax method?

Tags: php, jquery

The below JQuery Ajax method does not work when i try to make a call from my localhost using wamp to a php file which is located on a remote webserver. However it works fine if they both are on the same webserver. I believe i have turned on the crossDomain still not able to make cross domain calls ?

```
  <script>
             $(function() {

                $("#callAjax").click(function() {
                    var theName = $.trim($("#theName").val());

                    if(theName.length > 0)
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                          type: "GET",
                          url: "http://www.bcbustransit.uni.me/callajax.php",
                          data: ({name: theName}),
                          crossDomain: true,
                          cache: false,
                          dataType: "text",
                          success: onSuccess
                        });
                    }
                });

                $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
                 $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
                });

                function onSuccess(data)
                {
                    $("#resultLog").html("Result: " + data);
                }

            });


        </script>
```

.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("freehosting","xyz","xyz","xyz","3306");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


mysqli_select_db($con,"u197344625_cfv");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cfv_businfofull WHERE busnumber = 1 ");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Bus Number</th>
<th>StopNames</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Day Of Week </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['BusNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['StopNames'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Timings'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DayOfWeek'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: I tried changing the dataType to jsoup as well as json but that did not work ?

Comment: Unless you enable cross-origin (CORS) support on your server, you will have to switch to JSONP and change your server to support the callback that JSONP uses and package the results into that callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

In your case, you can just add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header with response on your Server side. Note, that instead of `*` you should use only  trusted domains.

Comment: Hi Castt thanks for the response adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to my php file worked but like you said instead of * i need to put trusted domains. How will that work for my app because i am going to convert my html file to .apk for andriod app and then distribute it on the market ?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue, as long as you specify only your trusted server in the header. This way your app will be much secure and will be protected from XSS injections. As mentioned above, you might consider JSONP as well.